# How to run headless Firefox profile manager? How run Firefox profile manager in docker?

Tags: selenium, firefox, docker, headless

I need to add my existing firefox profile to profile manager, how i can do this in docker container? because i can not run firefox profile manager in container. I need this to run selenium server with custom profile, new implementation off this option in selenium server need just name of profile, but when i copy my profile to

> ~/.mozilla/firefox/profilename

and run selenium server with

> -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=profilename

selenium can not see profile. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a kind of solution:

run docker container like this:

> docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
>   selenium/standalone-firefox /bin/bash

It`s works like a proxy for display, now all gui app from docker container will be showed on host machine display, that gives you ability to start firefox profile manager standart way:

> firefox -P

after that you can add profile or create new one, close manager, and if you run headless selenium server you need to

> export DISPLAY=":99"

i guess.